# How to ignore static dependencies when using Archunit

Tags: java, archunit

In one of my Archunit tests, I am checking (for example) that only classes in the service layer are depended on by classes in the presentation layer.

This test is failing because, as far as I am able to determine, some classes in the presentation layer have static imports of constants in other non-service layers.

How can I mitigate for this? One idea I have is to exclude static imports. How can I do this, using the fluent API?

Comment: Can you make your question a bit more specific: Which test is failing and how? Otheriwse it might be difficult to answer. Note that the concept of a static import does not exists at byte code level. In addition, primitive or `String` constants are inlined in the byte code of the importing class, and ArchUnit (in the current version 0.21.0) does not detect a dependency, cf. [ArchUnit#554](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/554) and [ArchUnit#298](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/298#issuecomment-577038056).

Comment: Your comment is fair, and it's interesting, your fact, that "the concept of a static import does not exists[sic] at byte code level", which also appears to be true, but those two resources that I sited in my accepted answer appear to be all one would need to get started with Archunit.

Comment: I agree that the [ArchUnit User Guide](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html) should hopefully help to get started.  I just didn't see that your question _"How to ignore static dependencies when using Archunit"_ asked for that... 

Comment: Quite right, In fact , your revelation about static imports, could be fashioned into an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is enough between [this](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html) and [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-archunit-intro) to guide you(us).

But, as @Manfred pointed out in the comments, static imports do not exist at byte code level, so this is not a problem, and I actually discovered that my issue was not caused by static imports, rather I just needed to grow my list of acceptable dependencies.